# returning an Object with parameters that are Getters?

Tags: java, oop, object

My question is i have the following code :

```
public Card getCard(int index) {
if (index <=0 || index > cardKeys.length)
return null;
else
return new Card(getSuit(index),getRank(index));
}
```

which i have filled in however my Junit tests say that there is an error..  i think it means if the index is less than or greater than the cardkeys array then return null 
else return an object of type Card with parameters **getRank** and **GetSuit**

ill also post the getters if that helps :

```
public int getSuit(int index) {
    if(index < 0 || index >= getSize())
        return 0;
    return (cardKeys[index]-1)/13 + 1;
}

public int getRank(int index) {
    if(index < 0 || index >= getSize())
        return 0;
    return (cardKeys[index]-1)%13 + 1;
}
```

ALSO NOTE: im not loooking for an answer to my assignment i just need some help in finding a different way to approach it

Thanks heaps guys 
Renx

Comment: Citing: "my Junit tests say that there is an error". And the error is?

Comment: Try running your test in debug mode and step through your code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: use try catch to trace the errors/Exceptions

Comment: Is 0 an allowed `index` when calling `getSuit()`? If not I'd first remove the range checking in `getSuit()` and `getRank()` methods so you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` near where the error is in your code and not some undefined and hard to debug malfunction later on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

`if (index < 0 || index >= cardKeys.length)`

You have mistakenly added the condition equal here `index <= 0`. The index can be `0` and it is valid and the index should be lesser than `cardKeys.length` as well

Comment: If it is an array, `cardKeys.length` should be out-of-bounds. But @Alex didn't say what type of collection is used ;)

Comment: ha ha :) updated the `cardKeys.length` logic as well, Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the help all unfortunately @scheintod im not allowed to use anything other than the arrays theyve given me otherwise i would of!

Ill try and debug the error and update, i think it has something to do with the getters however im not entirely sure yet haha

also thanks to octopus ill try that now

Comment: wait now i have a failure instead of an error octopus D:

Answer (score 0):

I like to offer you a different approach:

Since there are only 52 (53) distinct cards (if you try to implement poker) build an enum like that:

```
enum Card { SA, S1, S2, ..., SK, HA, H1, ... )
```

If you like to get fancy use other enums for color / value:

```
enum CardColor { SPADE, HEART, ... }
enum CardValue { ACE, TWO, ..., QUEEN, HEART }
```

and put it in Card:

```
enum Card {
    SA( Spade, ACE ), S2( Spade, TWO ) ...
    CardColor color,
    CardValue value
    public Card( CardColor color, CardValue value ){
        this.color = color;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

From there on you can easily use EnumSet to manage them or put them into Lists and so on.